# python urllib2 download size

Tags: python, download, urllib2, filesize

iwant to download a file with the urllib2, and meanwhile i want to display a progress bar..
but how can i get the actual downloaded filesize?

my current code is

```
ul = urllib2.urlopen('www.file.com/blafoo.iso')
data = ul.get_data()
```

or

```
open('file.iso', 'w').write(ul.read())
```

The data is first written to the file, if the whole download is recieved from the website.
how can i access the downloaded data size?

Thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried `urllib.urlretrieve` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of a text progress bar using the awesome [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library and the [progressbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.2) library:

```
import requests
import progressbar

ISO = "http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts"
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 # 1MB

r = requests.get(ISO)
total_size = int(r.headers['content-length'])
pbar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=total_size).start()

file_contents = ""
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE):
    file_contents += chunk
    pbar.update(len(file_contents))
```

This is what I see in the console while running:

```
$ python requests_progress.py
 90% |############################   |
```

*Edit: some notes:*

- Not all servers provide a content-length header, so in that case, you can't provide a percentage
- You might not want to read the whole file in memory if it's big. You can write the chunks to a file, or somewhere else.

Comment: I like the progress bar library! Reading a whole ISO image into memory isn't a good idea though. Also some additional handling is needed for when the Content-length header is missing (the server isn't required to send it).

Comment: added notes about content-length and file in memory

Comment: got it working with a progressbar. case sensitive for the content-length :)
Now its quite awesome ! thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You can use `info` function of urllib2 which returns `the meta-information of the page` and than you can use `getheaders` to access `Content-Length`.

For example, let's calculate the download size of `Ubuntu 12.04 ISO`

```
>>> info = urllib2.urlopen('http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/releases//precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso')
>>> size = int(info.info().getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
>>> size/1024/1024
701
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2
with open('file.iso', 'wb') as output: # Note binary mode otherwise you'll corrupt the file
    with urllib2.urlopen('www.file.com/blafoo.iso') as ul:
        CHUNK_SIZE = 8192
        bytes_read = 0
        while True:
            data = ul.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
            bytes_read += len(data) # Update progress bar with this value
            output.write(data)
            if len(data) < CHUNK_SIZE: #EOF
                break
```