# Python-- Extracting http headers

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
req = urllib2.Request
var1 = req.get_header('var1', default=None)
logging.info(var1)
var2 = req.get_header('var2', default=None)
logging.info(var2)
var3= req.get_header('var3', default=None)
logging.info(var3)
var4 = req.get_header('var4', default=None)
logging.info(var4)
```

Wrote the above python script to extract http headers, but getting following error when running on Google App Engine.

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: unbound method get_header() must be called with Request instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~##############/##########/@@@@@@@@@.py", line 10, in <module>
    var1= req.get_header('var1', default=None)
```

New to Python development for App Engine, so unable to figure out the error.

Comment: Have a look at [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831845/how-to-call-urllib2-get-header-method) about `getheader`.

Comment: Well, at the minimum you need to make an instance of Request like this `req = urllib2.Request(url)`

Comment: If the script for extracting headers is inside a web page(python coded). Using Advanced rest client(java based) I am sending the headers to the python web-page using GET. Getting the following error in app engine:: <class 'google.appengine.api.urlfetch_errors.InvalidURLError'>: App cannot fetch the same URL as the one used for the request.

Comment: I am trying to pass certain parameters from java web application to python script hosted on App Engine which uses those parameter's value for computation. The scenario for getting such error.

Comment: You don't need `urllib2` at all, just do as @DanielRoseman said in his answer below

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be doing something *very* strange: you are making a web request from your handler to the URL serving the same handler, and then trying to get the headers of the request you're actually making. Why would you do this? It makes no sense at all.

I *think* what you actually want to do is to get the headers from the request object that's already being passed to the handler, which of course is available via `self.request`.

Comment: More specifically- `self.request.headers` (a dict). But yes what Daniel suggests here is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can get like this,

```
>>> req = urllib2.Request("http://www.google.com")
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> response.info().getheader('Content-Type')
'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9'
>>>
```

Comment: If the script for extracting headers is inside a web page(python coded). Using Advanced rest client(java based) I am sending the headers to the python web-page using GET. Getting the following error in app engine:: <class 'google.appengine.api.urlfetch_errors.InvalidURLError'>: App cannot fetch the same URL as the one used for the request.